# saving the values of drop down menu into a cookie by php

Tags: php, html, cookies

I am trying to save the values of my drop down menu into a cookie! But the cookie shows a different value! Here is php code for it:

```
if (isset($_POST['myselection'])){

$chooseone=$_POST['myselection'];
setcookie ("chosenlang",$chooseone, $t);
$setobr=$_COOKIE['chosenlang'];

}
```

And this is the HTML part:

```
<form method="post" action="">

<select name="myselection" id="myselection" onchange="this.form.submit();">
<option value="choose">choose your language:</option>
<option value="Eng">Eng</option>
<option value="Esp">Esp</option>
</select>

</form>
```

The problem is that $setobr, shows $chosenone with a delay; meaning that when I print both, it first shows the opposite selection, and then the same selection!

Does anyone know why is that?

Comment: Where is your PHP code in relation to your HTML code (above, below)?

Comment: In your php is $myselection supposed to be $chooseone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set a cookie with `setcookie()`, you are telling the browser to send back this value ON THE NEXT REQUEST and any thereafter, until the cookie is changed, expires or is deleted.

`$_COOKIE` is not updated by this function call. This is intentional.

Comment: Yes! You're right! But do you know any way to fix it? And I still don't understand why when I set "Eng", it sets "ESP" instead! while it shouldn't set anything that way!

Comment: What should be "fixed"? I cannot see any code, you only paraphrase what your code might do, and this might not tell the whole story and might conceal errors.

Comment: There's no error! It's just that I want to save the values of the drop down menu into the cookie. And the only problem is that it sets it with one step delay! Meaning as you said, it sets it in the NEXT REQUEST after the cookie was changed!

Comment: Yes, and that's how it works. If you do not want to wait for the next request, do not read the selected language from $_COOKIE, but check if you got a cookie (maybe not), and check if you got your form back (maybe not), and from all these info you select the language the user wishes - or the default one because the user did not select anything - and put it into a new variable.

Answer (score 0):

Can you double check this line

```
setcookie ("chosenlang",$myselection, $t);
```

I hope it should be $chooseone not $myselection.

Comment: Yes! I have typed it wrong! Thanks, I fixed it now, but still the same problem!!!

Answer (score 0):

This does not work:

```
    setcookie("chosenlang", $chooseone, $t);
    $setobr = $_COOKIE['chosenlang'];
```

The [`$_COOKIE` superglobal<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/%24_cookie) only contains cookies that are part of the request. As you're just setting that cookie for the response, it will be available in the *next* request only.

Streamlining it *might* be what you're looking for:

```
    setcookie("chosenlang", $chooseone, $t);
    $setobr = $_COOKIE['chosenlang'] = $chooseone;
```

Take care. Also use the manual, it normally explains these things. [http://php.net/$_cookie](http://php.net/%24_cookie)